# Getting error "A set statement must have a variable or array element target" when trying to Set a Tuple using Q#

Tags: .net, quantum-computing, q#

I'm using Q# and [quantum dev kit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/quantum/development-kit).

I've declared this method

```
operation Superdense(here : Qubit, there : Qubit) : (Result, Result)
```

I try to use `mutable` variables and then `set` to hold the results of calling this method, as so:

```
    mutable resA = Zero;
    mutable resB = Zero;
    set (resA,resB) = Superdense(qubits[0],qubits[1]);
```

But in doing so I get this compile-time error:

> A set statement must have a variable or array element target

If I use `let` instead, it works fine

```
let (resA,resB) = Superdense(qubits[0],qubits[1]);
```

Could anyone tell me why I can't use `mutable` + `set` in this way to hold the `(Result,Result)` tuple-type result of my method?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Currently (as of 0.2.* version) the compiler supports tuple decomposition at immutable binding (`let`) but not at mutable binding (`mutable`) or rebinding (`set`). Thank you for the suggestion, it does make perfect sense to unify tuple decomposition support to cover all three scenarios.

As a side note, we're tracking feature requests at https://quantum.uservoice.com/forums/906208-q-language, so you might want to add suggestions there to make sure they get on our radar.

Comment: Our recent 0.3 release adds this feature.